# How to use `PreAnalyzedField` in SOLR to store annotations?

Tags: solr, lucene, named-entity-recognition

Using Solr 8.1.1 (running in cloud mode).

I cannot get the `PreAnalyzedField` - specifically the one with `JsonPreAnalyzedParser` to work fully.

Following the: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/working-with-external-files-and-processes.html#the-preanalyzedfield-type

My field and type definition:

```xml
  <fieldType name="preanalyzed" class="solr.PreAnalyzedField" parserImpl="org.apache.solr.schema.JsonPreAnalyzedParser">
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>


  <field name="pre" type="preanalyzed" indexed="true" termOffsets="true"
         stored="true" termPositions="true" termVectors="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

I add a test document like this:

```xml
<doc>
    <field name="document_id">json_doc</field>
    <field name="author">XML AUTHOR</field>
    <field name="pre">{
                            "v": "1",
                            str: "This is two sentences"
                            "tokens": [
    {"t": "This", "s": 0, "e": 4, "y": "word"},
    {"t": "two", "s": 8, "e": 11, "y": "word"}]
                         }</field>
  </doc>
```

I would like to be able to get the `pre.tokens` array in a query response.

When I query "everything"

`/select?q=*:*`

```json
{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "document_id":"json_doc",
        "author":["XML AUTHOR"],
        "pre":"This is two sentences",
        "_version_":1649822942659346432}]
}
```

The `tokens` array is not present in pre.

I know those tokens are somehow saved (so the document indexing works) - because when I query with highlighting on `pre`:

```json
{
    "params":{
      "q":"pre:two",
      "hl":"on",
      "hl.fl":"pre"
    },
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "document_id":"json_doc",
        "author":["XML AUTHOR"],
        "pre":"This is two sentences",
        "_version_":1649822942659346432}]
  },
  "highlighting":{
    "json_doc":{
      "pre":["This is <em>two</em> sentences"]
    }
  }
}
```

1. How do I get the tokens array returned in the query?
2. My ultimate goals is to do NER on the field using spacy and store the annotations in SOLR, so that I can query with something like 
   `q=document_content:(Person:Paris Hilton)` which would return documents containing entities of type: Person (the `y` field in the tokens) and name "Paris Hilton".

Really I would like to do something like I think is happening here in this "mapper annotated text" plugin in Elastic Search:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/search-for-things-not-strings-with-the-annotated-text-plugin

I have read all the support tickets in SOLR and some Java pertaining to PreAnalyzedFields:
This was especially interesting:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11764

Maybe I should be using this?
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_2_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/PreAnalyzedUpdateProcessorFactory.html

Comment: Is there anything indicating that the pre analyzed field should be able to return its tokens? None of the other fields do this; the input format is separate from the output format; the pre analyzed field uses the data you've given it to construct the tokens instead of running through the regular chain. It'd also need special processing on the way out to support returning the tokens (the JSON part is an implementation detail of the PreAnalyzedField)

Comment: I guess, I did not get the purpose of this.
How does the 'type of the token' the `y` element play into this. How is it used in the queries?

Comment: My _guess_ is that it's the same mechanism used by certain tokenizers to classify the tokens generated from the stream. There's also the [Type as Payload Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/filter-descriptions.html#type-as-payload-filter) (and the same as a synonym and the type filter which keeps matching types) that works with these values. In addition you can create your own query parser (or [use one of the existing ones](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/other-parsers.html#payload-query-parsers)) to enhance your queries with the metainformation provided in the field.

Comment: you may use the Luke request handler to get a list of tokens with a request like http://<hostname>:<port>/solr/<core name>/Luke?fl=<your field with preanalyzed values>&id=<unique key field value of the document>

See: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/luke-request-handler.html